# Oracle View based on "Offsets" of a Table Column

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

So I have this Table that I need to create a view from, We'll call it TABLEABC. The thing about this table is that it has 2 Columns. Column 1 we'll call C1 and it's a CHAR(25) column.
Easy enough.

The tricky part is the next column....and what I need to do with it.
We'll call it C2 and it is 600 Bytes!

Why you may ask? Well it's 600 characters because I am storing data in it based on offsets.

For instance:
NAME1 is size:15 Beginning Offset:1 Ending Offset:12
NAME2 is size:45 Beginning offset:13 Ending Offset: 49

So basically I need to store this Column based on the offsets, AND the "Offset Named" need to be specific, IE NAME1/NAME2 (Actually called different things, but Name1/Name2 for now)
There are also like 15 of these offsets.

Now i've done a bit of Oracle admin stuff, but just your basic stuff. I know SQL Server better but this is way beyond what Im used to doing, but im always looking for a challenge. Views are also sorta new to me. So that makes it even more difficult.

I figure maybe this would be a SUBSTR function, like:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(C2, 1, 12) As NAME1 from TABLE
```

Would that work? I've not done anything with Stored Procedures, so maybe theirs a better way?

edit:

So for a sample wise, (I would need to add the different offsets) would something like this work. (im not sure how to arrange the select statements, can I just add them on top of each other? Like does this work (assuming I add the rest of the selects?) and would anything need to be added at the end?

> CREATE VIEW VIEW1 AS
>    SELECT C1 FROM TABLE
>    SELECT SUBSTR(C2, 1,12) As 'NAME1' from TABLE
>    SELECT SUBSTR(C2, 13, 45) As 'NAME2' from TABLE

Comment: if the positions are fixed the `substr` is the way to go. if you are planning on quering the table often i would recommand creating a `materizlied view`.

Comment: In general, `SUBSTR` is your best bet. You probably won't have to resort to stored procedures. A couple other things: (a) your question says `NAME1` is size 15, which I think is in error; it confuses things a bit, and (b) ) if this is a "real" view then as someone who's done some admin work you know it's not the best way to store data. Is there a reason `C2` ended up like it is?

Comment: This is not my database fortunately haah (but I was assigned to this particular task), so I have no idea why it's like this. I believe it was originally used for printing. Unfortunately it can't be changed or lets say it "won't" be changed haha.

Comment: @EdGibbs, Made an edit: Would what I put above work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
CREATE VIEW VIEW1 AS
  SELECT
    C1,
    SUBSTR(C2, 1,12) AS NAME1,
    SELECT SUBSTR(C2, 13, 45) AS NAME2
  FROM
    TABLE1;
```

would work fine.

Comment: Awesome thank you! Wouldn't I need the table name in there somewhere?

Comment: Of course, oops! A view is just a named select statement, ie `create view <name> as <select_statement>;`

Comment: In the select statements, would the NAME1/NAME2 need "double quotes" or 'single quotes' or neither? like for instance if it was THE NAME

Comment: You need to use double quotes only if you really want your column name to contain a space or be lower or mixed case. Otherwise quotes aren't necessary (and Oracle stores your column name in upper case).